# I have multiple records against an ID, I want to collapse the data as a single record in select statment

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I have data as below:

```
COMPANY_ID  DATA
17           A
17           B
17           C
16           X
16           Y
16           X
```

And i want to select it as below:

```
COMPANY_ID  DATA
17          A,B,C
16          X,Y,Z
```

Comment: can you use distinct ?

Comment: I assume you mean `16          X,X,Y`, given your input data

Answer (score 1):

You may need [`LISTAGG`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/LISTAGG.htm#SQLRF30030) and aggregation:

```
select company_id, listagg(data, ',') within group ( order by data) as data
from yourTable
group by company_id
```

Which gives, with your input data:

```
COMPANY_ID DATA
---------- ----------
        16 X,X,Y
        17 A,B,C
```

Notice that I assumed that your needed result (or the input data) contains a typo.